# trying to draw a shape from a dictionary

Tags: python, tkinter, shapes, tkinter-canvas

I want to be able to create the shape onto the canvas using the `drawOnCanvas` function:

```
drawOnCanvas(can, shape1)
drawOnCanvas(can, shape2)
```

where the shapes parameters are as follows and gives me the image in tkinter:

```
shape1 = {'bounds': [20, 20, 80, 50], 'kind': 'rect', 'fill': True}
```

[image]

This is my attempt to create the function, my issue is I can't properly figure out how to create the `shape` from the `dict`:

```
from tkinter import *

def drawOnCanvas(can, shape):
    bounds = shape[0]
    kind = shape[1]
    fill = shape[2]
    can.create_polygon(bounds, kind, fill)


# main program
root = Tk()
can = Canvas(root, width=200, height=100)
can.pack()
#define the shape parameters, bounds=coordinates; kind=rectangle/triangle; fill=black if True, white if False
shape1 = {'bounds': [20, 20, 80, 50], 'kind': 'rect', 'fill': True}
shape2 = {'bounds': [80, 50, 20, 35], 'kind': 'tri', 'fill': False}
drawOnCanvas(can, shape1)
drawOnCanvas(can, shape2)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It seems like you don't know how to access data from python dictionary.  Suggest you to spend time to go through some basic tutorial like in [`w3school`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/) or [`The Official Python Tutorial`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

`shape` is a `dict`, not a `list`; You cannot index into a `dict`: `bounds = shape[0]` throws a `KeyError`!

Maybe something like this is closer to what you are trying to do? The `drawOnCanvas` calls the `tk.canvas` methods corresponding to the shape in question, with the proper required arguments extracted and transformed from `shape`. (please note that triangles, if it is what `tri` refers to, are underdefined by a bounding box, so I omitted it):

```
import tkinter as tk


def drawOnCanvas(canvas, shape):
    canvas_create_methods = {'rect': canvas.create_rectangle}   # add more methods as you develop your app
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = shape['bounds']
    kind = shape['kind']
    fill = '' if not shape['fill'] else 'black'
    return canvas_create_methods[kind](x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=fill)


root = tk.Tk()
can = tk.Canvas(root, width=200, height=100)
can.pack()

#define the shape parameters, bounds=coordinates; kind=rectangle/triangle; fill=black if True, white if False
shape1 = {'bounds': [20, 20, 80, 50], 'kind': 'rect', 'fill': True}
drawOnCanvas(can, shape1)

root.mainloop()
```